# Subclass' method doesn't overwrite its superclass method

Tags: python, class, methods, super

Why the Sloop subclass's method get_info doesn't overwrite its superclass' method?

```
class Boat( object ):
    def __init__( self, name, loa ):
        """Create a new Boat( name, loa )"""
        self.name= name
        self.loa= loa
    def get_info(self):
        print "Boat:", self.name, "Size:", self.loa
        print "This is printed correctly"

class Catboat( Boat ):
    def __init__( self, sail_area, * args ):
        """Create a new Catboat( sail_area, name, loa )"""
        super(Catboat,self).__init__( * args )
        self.main_area= sail_area
    def get_info(self):
        #print dir(self)
        print "Boat:", self.name, "Size:", self.loa, "Sail area:", self.main_area
        print "This one also"

class Sloop( Catboat ):
    def __init__( self, jib_area, * args ):
        """Create a new Sloop( jib_area, main_area, name, loa )"""
        super(Sloop,self).__init__( * args )
        self.jib_area= jib_area
    def get_info(self):
        print "Boat:", self.name, "Size:", self.loa, "Sail area:", self.main_area,             "Jib_area:", self.jib_area
        print "This should be printed, but it's not"

boat1 = Boat("Titanic", 20)
catboat1 = Catboat(50, "Titanic", 40)
sloop1 = Sloop(70, 60, "Titanic", 50)

boat1.get_info()
catboat1.get_info()
sloop1.get_info()
```

'''

prints:

Boat: Titanic Size: 20
This is printed correctly
Boat: Titanic Size: 40 Sail area: 50
This one also
Boat: Titanic Size: 50 Sail area: 60
This one also

Expected:

Boat: Titanic Size: 20
This is printed correctly
Boat: Titanic Size: 40 Sail area: 50
This one also
Boat: Titanic Size: 50 Sail area: 60 Jib_area: 70
This should be printed, but it's not

"

Comment: Obviously your indentation should be wrong. Are you sure it's right and NOT as shown in this question?

Comment: Yes, indeed the indentation was wrong. However, it was correct in my IDE and the printed output was as presented above.

Comment: The problem was with the indentation. Code was copied from internet, and 4-spaces vs tab indentation was mixed up - therefore causing this problem. Code above is correct, and it prints out as expected.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Use the Expand Tabs option with a standard value (2, 4 usually). That will help you keep all your code uniform.

Comment: Geany. That's a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the indentation given in the question is right, then the sub classes do not have a get_info() function